# How I can create a function for create a plot with echarts4r?

Tags: r, function, echarts

Hello everyone and good night. I would like to know if it is possible to create a function to simplify the creation of a chart with Echarts4r in r. Im trying but I get the error `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.`. Anyone knows how I can fix it? The code im using is the following:

```
library(echarts4r)

graf_func <- function(dataframe, vary, varx){
  
  grafico <- base |> 
    e_charts(vary) |> 
    e_bar(varx) |> 
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
  
  return(grafico)
  
}

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = runif(10, min = 100, max = 200),
  var2 = runif(10, min = 10, max = 200)
)


graf_func(dataframe = df, vary = var1, varx = var2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the functions `e_charts_` and `e_bar_` and pass the column names as character.

```
library(echarts4r)

graf_func <- function(dataframe, vary, varx){
  
  grafico <- dataframe |> 
    e_charts_(vary) |> 
    e_bar_(varx) |> 
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
  
  return(grafico)
  
}

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = runif(10, min = 100, max = 200),
  var2 = runif(10, min = 10, max = 200)
)


graf_func(dataframe = df, vary = "var1", varx = "var2")
```